# SKIP_AUTOUIC for specific include file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have a file named `ui_helper.h` (can't rename). This file doesn't relate to `.ui` form definition, just a helper header. So I need to exclude this file from [`AUTOUIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html) processing. I tried the following:

```
set_source_files_properties(ui_helper.h PROPERTIES SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
```

but got an error:

```
AutoUic error
  -------------
  "SRC:some_unit.cpp"
  includes the uic file "ui_helper.h",
  but the user interface file "helper.ui"
  could not be found in the following directories 
    ...
```

I.e. I need actually to skip `some_unit.cpp` instead of `ui_helper.h`. And that works. But the header `ui_helper.h` can be included for many units, so I need to exclude all of these files. Furthermore some of them may include also other headers, e.g. `ui_form.h` (linked with `form.ui`), hence skip for that file can't be set.

Is there a way to specify only single `ui_helper.h` file to exclude from `AUTOUIC` processing?

Comment: You have to set the property on where you include the ui_foo.h file because there cmake gets it's information from if a ui-file should be processed.

Comment: If you can't rename you can introduce a new header with different name, which would include `ui_helper.h` and then use it instead of `ui_helper.h` everywhere. I guess it is your best bet as it seems that CMake considers properties of the files while processing them from the make file level only, not recursively testing every header included (at least for UIC). The docs also promise only that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is what you have been looking for:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_AUTOUIC.html

```
set_property(SOURCE file.h PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
set_property(SOURCE file.cpp PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
set_property(SOURCE widget.ui PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOUIC ON)
```

This source file property has some friends `SKIP_AUTOMOC`, `SKIP_AUTORCC`, etc.

And you should add it to the `add_library` command explicitly. Then CMake is aware of the file and doesn't try to create it from a UI file.